# How to use localStorage on this example?

Tags: javascript, html

Can you apply localStorage on this? If I click "Deduct", the id "slot" will reduce to 1. What I want to learn is how to apply localStorage. If the slot is 9, and if I will refresh/close the browser or restart the computer and run the program again, the slot will remain 9. I'm having a hard time on learning about localStorage, need help masters.

```
<script>
var availableSlot1 = 10;
var reduceSlot1 = function(valueToDeduct1){
    availableSlot1 = availableSlot1 - valueToDeduct1;
    document.getElementById('slot').innerHTML = availableSlot1;
    var x = storage.key(availableSlot1);
    if (availableSlot1 == 0){
        document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = "FULL";
        document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
    }
};
</script>

<p id="slot">10</p>
<a href="javascript:reduceSlot1(1)" id="button1">Deduct</a>

EDITED:
<script>
var slot = localStorage.getItem("slot");
if (typeof slot == "undefined") {
     slot = 10;
}
document.getElementById("slot").innerHTML = slot;

var reduceSlot1 = function reduceSlot(by) 
 {
  if (slot >= by) {
      slot -= by;
      document.getElementById("slot").innerHTML = slot;
       localStorage.setItem("slot", slot);
 } 
else {
      document.getElementById('slot').innerHTML = "FULL";
      document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
    }
 }
</script>
```

I followed the code but, it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/flocsy/mrhwK/

```
var slot = localStorage.getItem("slot");
if (slot == null) {
  slot = 10;
}
document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot;

function reduceSlot() {
    if (slot >= 1) {
        slot --;
        document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot;
        localStorage.setItem("slot", slot);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('x').innerText = "FULL";
        document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
    }
}

document.getElementById("button1").onclick = reduceSlot;
```

Comment: Ok I will try, so am i gonna erase already my script replace with that?

Comment: I edited my answer I hope now it's clear

Comment: I edited and it didn't work, please look the code above that I edited.

Comment: see now, I've added a link to jsfiddle, and it works there

Comment: thank you sir, but one problem when i click the button it reduces the slot and it's fine. assuming that the remaining slot is 9, but when i refresh my browser it goes back to 10 but when i click again it is already 8, because i already deducted it earlier. my concern is it is always display the slot to 10 when i refresh

Comment: that's strange, because the first 5 lines are there to take care of that.

Comment: your code in jsfiddle works fine, but when i copied it to a new html file it always displays 10 at first

Comment: are you sure my code runs? Is it possible there's a javascript error before it? Look at the javascript console, or even add breakpoint to my 1st line

Answer (score 1):

[**Live Demo of Local Storage**](http://jsfiddle.net/KCJsn/)

you can use local storage using `localStorage.name`, in place of name you can use any property.

```
var i = 1;
localStorage.name = i;
```

Comment: To be precise, `name` is not a "parameter" but property.

Comment: can you do the complete code @NaYan